# how to fix CheckBox?

Tags: android, checkbox

I have six CheckBoxes so, I need that if user is check the checkBox he can see button orange that available, but if he does not check the button is grey color and not available.
So, I tried to do that and the problem is, if the user check all the checkBoxes and after not check, the button grey is still available and does not change to orange.

this is my code of one checkBox:

```
 mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (mCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                mImageButtonOrange.setEnabled(true);
                mImageButtonOrange.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mImageButtonError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                mImageButtonOrange.setEnabled(false);
                mImageButtonOrange.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mImageButtonError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

The checkBox is checked, the orange button is available:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL2f4.png)

so, after we check, we want to unCheck, the button grey is available Although, the checkBox is checked and the button orange is not availble:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOhEg.png)

so, how I can change this, that after I uncheck the CheckBox and I have another checkBox that checks, the button orange is Visibility and button grey gone?

Comment: Add your checkboxes to a List, and add setOnCheckedChangeListener for each of the checkbox. Then you can show the orange button if any one of the checkboxes in the list is checked, otherwise show grey button when all are unchecked.

Comment: thanks you very much @PraveenSingh for you'r comment, do you have a example about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `RadioGroup` for the same and manage orange `Button` visibility using `RadioGroup` `onCheckedChange` event.

Put all the `RadioButton` inside `<RadioGroup></RadioGroup>` in xml .